# How to run a software from other drives rather than the root?

Tags: software-installation, blender

I downloaded the blender software from its official site and I read the installation procedure. It stated that blender can be run from any drives/partition on Ubuntu and all we must do is extract to the desired location.

But blender only runs on the root directory folder (/home for example). And I need it to run on my D drive where I have all my blend files from windows. So is there any way to run blender on any of my partitions?

Comment: Do you have a D: drive in Ubuntu? Why don't you use repository version? It's easier and safer to install: `sudo apt-get install blender` in Terminal.

Comment: no I don't want to use that, and moreover it installs blender in the /home directory. I want to know how to use the application by using the files from the compressed zip file which you download from the [blender](http://www.blender.org/download/) site. And I need that runnable in my other drives rather than the root. But anyway thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are talking about where Blender saves/loads user files. That paths are different from application's installation directories. Blender from repos doesn't install in `/home` directory. It has its main executable in `/usr/bin` and most of its required files in `/usr/share/blender`.

You might want to check this: `File` -> `User Preferences`

[image]

Anyway if you want to use the version from http://www.blender.org/ and not from Ubuntu repos just extract archive contents to any folder/drive you like and launch blender's main executable `blender`. If it doesn't work open a Terminal and `cd` to the folder where you extracted the archive then:

```
sudo chmod +x ./blender
./blender
```

Linux is not Windows. The so called `root` partition is Linux's main filesystem and any other partitions are mounted in folders that are in the `root` drive. No C, D, E... drives. Just one big filesystem where you can add contents from other partitions/disk drives/USB drives by mounting them to any folder you wish. If `blend files from windows` refers to Blender's setup file for Windows, then you should know it's useless on any Linux.

Comment: @ganezdragon but what about installing the repo version and changing those paths?

Comment: I have done as you said but there is an error
"./blender: Permission denied"
And as far as the repository and PPA version, Can I have the installed files in my local drive? rather than the root?

Comment: @ganezdragon no. If you install form the repo you must run simply `blender`

Comment: Is there any way I can just extract and run the software? Because I have lot of other software like android development kit,eclipse etc. which are in compressed zip format.